# pivot table - how to add percent by calculating using exist results - python

Tags: python

I have a table as below:

```
    after   before
a   200     630
b   750     852
c   457     76738
d   3205    32235
e   12408   188561
f   1192    497130
```

I'd like to add a percent result and expected result as below:

(*percent = after/(after+before)*)

```
    after   before  percent
a   200     630     0.240963855
b   750     852     0.468164794
c   457     76738   0.005920073
d   3205    32235   0.090434537
e   12408   188561  0.061740866
f   1192    497130  0.002392028
```

```
def get_percent(x):
  " for each value in row, return a percentage by after/(after+before) corresponds to "
  return np.array()
```

Thank you.

```
    after   before  percent
a   200     630     0.240963855
b   750     852     0.468164794
c   457     76738   0.005920073
d   3205    32235   0.090434537
e   12408   188561  0.061740866
f   1192    497130  0.002392028
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Helper function to get percentage values from our source data frame
def get_percent(sourceDataframe):
  " for each value in row, return a percentage by after/(after+before) corresponds to "
  sourceDataframe['percent'] = sourceDataframe['after']/(sourceDataframe['after'] + sourceDataframe['before'])

  return sourceDataframe

# Create our data frame here
original_Array = np.array( [ [200, 630] , [750, 852] , [457, 76738], [3205, 32235], [12408, 188561], [1192, 497130]])
names = [x for x in 'abcdef']
df = pd.DataFrame(original_Array, index=names, columns=['after', 'before'])

# Call our function here
new_Dataframe = get_percent(df)

# Print our output to the console
print(new_Dataframe)
```

That should yield an output like below:

```
   after  before   percent
a    200     630  0.240964
b    750     852  0.468165
c    457   76738  0.005920
d   3205   32235  0.090435
e  12408  188561  0.061741
f   1192  497130  0.002392
```

To control the decimal places in your display, you could edit the default used for printing a data frame like below:

```
pandas.set_option("display.precision", 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do

```py
df['percent'] = df.eval('after / (after + before)')
```

```
print(df)

   after  before   percent
a    200     630  0.240964
b    750     852  0.468165
c    457   76738  0.005920
d   3205   32235  0.090435
e  12408  188561  0.061741
f   1192  497130  0.002392
```